# Reference subkeys from external, remote JSON schema

Tags: validation, jsonschema

I have started working with JSON Schema in a project of mine. I am still having issues understanding how `$id` and `$ref` work together, and where *tools*, `$id`, `base_uri`, etc. com together. Here's a scenario:

I have my schema defined in a file `schema.json`.
This file is hosted on my website `https://example.com/schema.json`.
The `$id` of the schema is `https://example.com/schema/`.
The `$schema` is `"http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema"`.

I can use this schema in the validator at https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ by giving it a schema where the URL is referenced, and validation works (invalid instances fail, etc.).

```json
{
  "$ref": "https://example.com/schema.json"
}
```

I can resolve subkeys by using `"$ref": "https://example.com/schema.json#/properties/subkey"`. `"$ref": "https://example.com/schema#/properties/subkey"` doesn't resolve, perhaps because it's not findable in a schema store?

So now, if I wanted this to work - `"$ref": "https://example.com/schema#/properties/subkey"`, would I have to rename the file to simply `schema`? Or is there another way how this would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"schema" and "schema.json" point to different files, so you either need to rename the file to match the uri in the $ref, or change the $ref to refer to the correct filename.

This guide may help: [Structuring a complex schema](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html)

Comment: Right, $id always contains the absolute URI to the file itself (URL here), not a `schema` object that is autodiscovered or something? Asking because I've not seen many files with `.json` ending in the $id field. Perhaps coincidence...

Comment: The extension isn't necessary in the URI if only one file format is supported, or if different formats are returned depending on the `Accept` header, so many applications will choose to leave it out so the URIs look nicer.